# Incremental backup of postgresql database

Tags: backup, postgresql

We run a database server running PostgreSQL with database size of around 130GB growing at a rate of 500MB per day. We use HP Data Protector software to take backups of the database.

The issue here is that our database is on a GFS mounted partition and the current backup software license does not facilitate taking backups from GFS, NFS mounted partitions.

So, as a workaround, we planned to copy the database to a local partition using `pg_dump` utility and take backups from the local partition using data protector software. But I am not sure whether we can take incremental backups using `pg_dump`. Full backup everyday is not possible for us.

Please suggest steps for taking incremental backup of a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Check [SO:Best method for postgres incremental backup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529603/best-method-for-postgres-incremental-backup)

Answer (score 4):

The best method to incremental backup Postgres is to use periodic hot physical backups and continuous WAL archiving.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/continuous-archiving.html

The periodic physical backup can be done with rsync using the --copy-dest= option to take advantage of any previous copy reusing unchanged files.

This is a very effective way of backing up Postgres and can also be used to do Point In Time Recovery (PITR) in case of disaster.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at this SO Q&A titled: [Best method for postgres incremental backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529603/best-method-for-postgres-incremental-backup).

*excerpt of accepted answer*

> **Update:** [Check out Barman](http://www.pgbarman.org/) for an easier way to set up WAL archiving for backup.
>
> You can use [PostgreSQL's continuous WAL archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/continuous-archiving.html) method. First you need to set `wal_level=archive`, then do a full filesystem-level backup (between issuing `pg_start_backup()` and `pg_stop_backup()` commands) and then just copy over newer WAL files by configuring the `archive_command`option.

See that Q&A's answer for a run down of the advantages & disadvantages of this method.